# I need to stop the current event jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-events

**THIS HTML CODE**

```
<div id="functionality" style="padding: 10px 20px;">
    <span class="btn btn-xs btn-success" style="margin:2px; float: left;">flat earth account</span>
    <span class="btn btn-xs btn-success" style="margin:2px; float: left;">site preparation</span>
</div>
```

and I have this jQuery code:

```
$('#functionality>span').click(function() {
    var text = $(this).html();
    $('.function-content').fadeOut('fast', function() { 
        var div = text.replace(/ /g,"_");
        $('#functionality_calculation').delay(500).fadeIn('slow', function() {
            $(this).delay(500).fadeOut('slow', function() {
                $('#' + div).fadeIn('slow');
                var winHeight = $(window).height();
                var divHeight = $("#"+div).height();
                var scrollHeight = (divHeight - winHeight) / 2
                $('html, body').animate({
                        scrollTop: ($("#"+div).offset().top + scrollHeight) + 'px'
                    }, 'slow'
                );
            });
        });
    }); 
});
```

**NOW**

What I need is when I click on any span I need it to stop the active event (run event).

**WHAT I TRIED**

```
event.stopPropagation();
```

---

```
event.preventDefault();
```

---

When I click the span

1- show the loading

2- show the div

What I'm trying to do is while this process if I click on any other span I need it to stop the previous click event and start the new one.

```js
$('#functionality>span').click(function() {
  var text = $(this).html();
  $('.function-content').fadeOut('fast', function() { 
    var div = text.replace(/ /g,"_");
    $('#functionality_calculation').delay(500).fadeIn('slow', function() {
      $(this).delay(500).fadeOut('slow', function() {
        $('#' + div).fadeIn('slow');
        var winHeight = $(window).height();
        var divHeight = $("#"+div).height();
        var scrollHeight = (divHeight - winHeight) / 2
        $('html, body').animate({
          scrollTop: ($("#"+div).offset().top + scrollHeight) + 'px'
        }, 'fast'
       );
      });
    });
  }); 
});
```

```css
.btn {
      display: inline-block;
    padding: 6px 12px;
    margin-bottom: 0;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
    line-height: 1.428571429;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    cursor: pointer;
    background-image: none;
    border: 1px solid transparent;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    -o-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
    background: green;
    color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="functionality" style="padding: 10px 20px;">
    <span class="btn" style="margin:2px; float: left;">construction work</span>
    <span class="btn" style="margin:2px; float: left;">acts of sanitary wares</span>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div id="functionality_calculation" style="padding: 20px; display: none;">
  <img src="http://archbrella.com/img/load.gif" />
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div id="construction_work" class="function-content" style="display: none;">
  construction works
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div id="acts_of_sanitary_wares" class="function-content" style="display: none;">
  acts of sanitary wares

</div>
```

Comment: Stop how exactly, it's not even remotely clear what you're trying to do, but I do suspect you're really just looking for [`jQuery.fn.finish()`](https://api.jquery.com/finish/)

Comment: when i click the span 1- show the loading 2- show the div what i'm trying to do is while this process if i click on any other span i need it to stop the previous click event and start the new one

Comment: You can't stop the click event, once it's clicked, it's clicked, what you really mean is you want to stop the animations and everything that happens inside them, and `finish()` does that. Try `$('.function-content').finish().fadeOut('fast', function() { ...`

Comment: finish it will finish the exist event and clear all animation queue also the process is not only on one div and if i click on other span with finish it will show the previous result and i don't want that

Comment: If you just want to stop it **now**, do `$('.function-content').stop(true, true).fadeOut('fast', function() {...` instead

Comment: @adeneo i tried the stop and the finish what happen now is that it fires the click event but without stoping the prev one

Comment: Oh, I see, I think what you're really looking for is this -> https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/p75z9goh/1/

Comment: thanks a lot for your time @adeneo but what i need i need the new click event stop the prev one  and your jsfiddle not working with mine :(

Comment: @adeneo i'm just added the snippit of my code

Comment: This is callback hell..

Comment: @rishabhdev what you mean ?

Comment: @AlaaM.Jaddou please see the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea is to get the timestamp of the click event, and store the timestamp outside the callback. So outside variable will be updated with the latest click timestamp. Now we can check for each nested callbacks whether we want to get it executed when already some other click has happened(clickTime !== lastClickTime).

```js
var lastClickTime;
$('#functionality>span').click(function() {
  var text = $(this).html();
  var clickTime = Math.floor(Date.now());
  lastClickTime = clickTime;


  $('.function-content').fadeOut('fast', function() {

    if (lastClickTime == clickTime) {
      var div = text.replace(/ /g, "_");
      
      
      //stop the previous animation and reset for the new animation to start
      $('.function-content').hide();
      $('#functionality_calculation').stop();
      $('#functionality_calculation').hide();

      $('#functionality_calculation').fadeIn(500, function() {

        if (lastClickTime == clickTime) {

          $(this).delay(500).fadeOut('slow', function() {

            if (lastClickTime == clickTime) {
              $('#' + div).fadeIn('slow');
              var winHeight = $(window).height();
              var divHeight = $("#" + div).height();
              var scrollHeight = (divHeight - winHeight) / 2;

              $('html, body').animate({
                scrollTop: ($("#" + div).offset().top + scrollHeight) + 'px'
              }, 'fast');
            }
          });


        } else {
          $(this).hide();
        }

      });
    }
  });

});
```

```css
.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 6px 12px;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: normal;
  line-height: 1.428571429;
  text-align: center;
  white-space: nowrap;
  vertical-align: middle;
  cursor: pointer;
  background-image: none;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  border-radius: 4px;
  -webkit-user-select: none;
  -moz-user-select: none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  -o-user-select: none;
  user-select: none;
  background: green;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="functionality" style="padding: 10px 20px;">
  <span class="btn" style="margin:2px; float: left;">construction work</span>
  <span class="btn" style="margin:2px; float: left;">acts of sanitary wares</span>
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div id="functionality_calculation" style="padding: 20px; display: none;">
  <img src="http://archbrella.com/img/load.gif" />
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div id="construction_work" class="function-content" style="display: none;">
  construction works
</div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div id="acts_of_sanitary_wares" class="function-content" style="display: none;">
  acts of sanitary wares

</div>
```

Best on this logic, this is the best i could do.. Your code is in a messy state called as callback hell. When dealing with js callbacks we always try to avoid such situation.
Suggested readings for you :
 http://callbackhell.com/ 
https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: i got what you need to do i will try it now and give my feedback to you.

Comment: i've tried your code what happen the loading image is fading in and out 10 times then fadeout for 1 sec then fadeIn loading and the div but the div appear is the last called.

Comment: Testing `lastClickTime == clickTime` is a somewhat arcane way of stopping an animation sequence, when jQuery's `.stop()` or `.finish()` are available.

Comment: Besides, this approach won't stop the current animation dead - it will only prevent the next animation in the sequence from starting.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 the `.stop()` and the `.finish()` not doing what i'm trying to do so he came with this solution

Comment: If `.stop()` or `.finish()` aren't working then it's because you're not using them correctly.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 you could use the code above and do it correctly if you please.

Answer (score 1):

On each click, you need to :

- stop the current animation immediately, and hence stop the animation sequence,
- store enough data to identify the elements involved in the animation sequence about to be initiated,
- initiate the animation sequence.

With a bit of flattening, the animation sequence should look like this :

```
// Object in outer scope for remembering the current animation elements.
var current = {
    span: null,
    div: null,
    otherElements: $('html, body, .function-content, #functionality_calculation')
};

$('#functionality>span').click(function() {
    if(current.span) {
        // Stop all animations in the current animation sequence.
        // It's not important which, if any, is currently being animated - just stop them all.
        current.otherElements.add(current.span).add(current.div).stop(true);

        // It's hard to tell exactly what's right here, but something like this,
        // to get the various animated elements to an appropriate start state. ..
        curent.span.hide(); //??
        curent.div.hide(); //??
        $('.function-content').show(); //??
        $('#functionality_calculation').hide(); //??
    }
    // Remember `this` and its corresponding div for next time round
    current.span = this;
    current.div = $('#' + $(this).html().replace(/ /g, "_"));

    //Now set up the animation sequence as a .then() chain.
    $('.function-content').fadeOut('fast').delay(500).promise()
    .then(function() {
        return $('#functionality_calculation').fadeIn('slow').delay(500).promise();
    })
    .then(function() {
        return $(this).fadeOut('slow').promise();
    })
    .then(function() {
        current.div.fadeIn('slow');
        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: (current.div.offset().top + (current.div.height() - $(window).height()) / 2) + 'px'
        }, 'slow');
    });
});
```

Note that by returning a promise from each stage of the animation sequence, the next stage will wait for its completion.

Comment: the thing i don't need it to wait :( i need to change it immediately.

Comment: @AlaaM.Jaddou, that's the whole point. This solution waits only for each stage to complete before starting the next stage (as required) but stops immediately in response to another click.